# How to switch to full-width Latin characters with ibus-libpinyin?

Tags: ibus, chinese, pinyin

I know it is possible to start writing in full-width characters when using ibus-libpinyin because I've done it by accident sometimes. Now I want to do it intentionally. How do I do that? What is the shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Matigo's answer, I could found the issue:

1. I went to the "Preferences" menu from libpinyin:

[image: A menu from an indicator app, with the "Preferences" option highlighted.]

2. In the window that opened, I went to the "Shortcuts" tab.
3. There, I could see the shortcut to "Switch English/Chinese" was set to <kbd>Shift</kbd> alone.

[image: The dialog where one can change the shortcut keys for iBus-pinyin. There, the command "Switch Chinese/English" is set to Shift.]

<kbd>Shift</kbd> works for me. If I wanted, I could change that by selecting the command and clicking on "Edit."

Answer (score 1):

So long as you haven't modified the shortcuts, you'll need to use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Think "F" for "Full Width" if you need a simple way to remember

Comment: Thank you! I bet it was somehow changed here, though, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> didn't work. But your answer really helped me; I went to libpinyin's preferences and found that the key was <kbd>Shift</kbd>. So, thank you so much for giving me the idea to check there :)